# making a loop for click function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make the following functions work continually as a loop as it is to control open panels in an accordion but I can only seem to get this function to run the once to add the class to the initial clicked element (upon 1st click) and once again to remove the class (upon 2nd click) from the element upon clicking another panel in the accordion. Then it no longer adds or removes classes with the click function? Please help, I am pretty new to all this! Thanks

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('dt').click(function() {
    //alert( "Handler for .click() called." );

    $(this).next().andSelf().addClass('.openAcc');
    $('dt').click(function() {
      $('dt').next().andSelf().removeClass('.openAcc');

    });
  });
});
```

basically i want to be able to click on any dt element in the accordion and either turn on or off the previous/current accordions class

Comment: You can share the html file, and try to better explain what you want to do!

Comment: You don't assign another click handler to do that. You simply remove the `.openAcc` from anything that has it before you add it to the clicked element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding new click handlers *every* time you click, and they will be active at the same time, one will undo the effect of the other, ...etc.

It often is a bad sign when event handlers are assigned within a handler for the same event.

In fact, jQuery has a nice function for what you want: `toggleClass`:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('dt').click(function() {
        $(this).next().andSelf().toggleClass('.openAcc');
    });
});
```

Comment: excellent, thanks for your help @trincot really new to all this so learn so much by little things like that. Thanks again

Comment: @PaulStephenDavis: Your question states that you want to close the previous one clicked when clicking a new one. This doesn't do that. You should change the wording of your question if this is the solution you needed.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of worrying about a loop, you can just remove all `.openAcc` classes, then add it to the current one.

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('dt').click(function() {
    //alert( "Handler for .click() called." );

        $('.openAcc').removeClass('.openAcc');
        $(this).next().andSelf().addClass('.openAcc');

    });
});
```

Optimized code with help from @squint

Comment: This is the way if I understood the question, though you can optimize a little with `$(".openAcc").removeClass(".openAcc")`